# how to filter data with a sql query using sessions

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session

I have a database I am using to create pie charts with D3.js. I have made a filter to sort the data by year and month using a form, when you submit, a session is created based on the dropdown options. And i am using the sessions in my query.

[image]

I have attached an image for a better understanding, currently my query is sorting the overall data together but not independently. for example I would like to sort data in year 2016 **or** by month January.

I have been playing around it with but I can't seem to get it right, they should work **both** independent of each other **and** together, I have gotten only as far as or the other. here is my code

```
// this is used to reset the graphs back to default 
            if ($_SESSION['filteryear'] == 0 && $_SESSION['filtermonth'] == 0) {
                $sql = "SELECT value, COUNT(*) AS count
                FROM sodsurvey LEFT OUTER JOIN age
                ON sodsurvey.age_id = age.id 
                WHERE value IS NOT NULL AND office_id = " . $office_id . " 
                GROUP BY age_id; ";
            } else {
                $sql = "SELECT value, COUNT(*) AS count
                FROM sodsurvey LEFT OUTER JOIN age
                ON sodsurvey.age_id = age.id 
                WHERE value IS NOT NULL AND office_id = " . $office_id . " 
                AND month = " . $_SESSION['filtermonth'] . " 
                AND year = " . $_SESSION['filteryear'] . " 
                GROUP BY age_id; ";
            }

            $result = $dbh->prepare($sql);//prepares query  
            $result->execute();
```

@Alox here is the code

```
$EX_SQL="";

if ($_SESSION['filteryear'] != 0 && $_SESSION['filtermonth'] != 0) {
    $EX_SQL=" AND month = " . $_SESSION['filtermonth'] . " AND year = " . $_SESSION['filteryear'] . "";
} else if($_SESSION['filteryear'] != 0) {
    $EX_SQL=" AND month = " . $_SESSION['filtermonth'] . "";
} else {
   $EX_SQL=" AND year = " . $_SESSION['filteryear'] . "";
}

        $sql = "SELECT value, COUNT(*) AS count
               FROM sodsurvey LEFT OUTER JOIN age
               ON sodsurvey.age_id = age.id 
               WHERE value IS NOT NULL AND office_id = " . $office_id . "
               ".$EX_SQL."
                GROUP BY age_id; ";

            $result = $dbh->prepare($sql);//prepares query  
            $result->execute();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more experiments I found the solution with this

```
        $filter = "";

        if ($_SESSION['filteryear'] != 0 && $_SESSION['filtermonth'] != 0) {
            $filter = "AND year = " . $_SESSION['filteryear'] . " AND month = " . $_SESSION['filtermonth'] . "";
        } else if ($_SESSION['filteryear'] != 0 || $_SESSION['filtermonth'] != 0) {
            $filter = "AND (year = " . $_SESSION['filteryear'] . " OR month = " . $_SESSION['filtermonth'] . ")";
        }

        $sql = "SELECT value, COUNT(*) AS count
        FROM sodsurvey LEFT OUTER JOIN age
        ON sodsurvey.age_id = age.id 
        WHERE value IS NOT NULL AND office_id = " . $office_id . "
        ".$filter."
        GROUP BY age_id; ";
```

Thank you for pointing me to the right direction

Answer (score 0):

There would be 3 cases.

1. You have both Year **AND** Month.
2. You either have Month **OR** Year.
3. You don't have any of them.

Your current **PHP** code only supports 2 cases. (1st and 3rd) You should add another **else if** block.

For better optimization what you can do is just replace the SQL string according to the parameters. Like this,

```
$EX_SQL="";

if ($_SESSION['filteryear'] != 0 && $_SESSION['filtermonth'] != 0) {
    $EX_SQL=" AND month = " . $_SESSION['filtermonth'] . " AND year = " . $_SESSION['filteryear'] . "";
} else if($_SESSION['filteryear'] != 0) {
    $EX_SQL=" AND month = " . $_SESSION['filtermonth'] . "";
} else {
   $EX_SQL=" AND year = " . $_SESSION['filteryear'] . "";
}
```

And User `EX_SQL` string in query like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT value, COUNT(*) AS count FROM sodsurvey LEFT OUTER JOIN age ON sodsurvey.age_id = age.id WHERE value IS NOT NULL AND office_id=".$office_id." ".$EX_SQL." GROUP BY age_id; ";
```

Above code should cover all 3 cases.

Comment: echo `$sql` just after creating it. What you're getting?

Comment: when i open the file i see this 

(SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND year = 0 GROUP BY age_id' at line 5)

Comment: It seems there is syntax error in SQL, Can you print the SQL here? There might be single space issue.

Comment: I can't in comments it's too long, should i post in the question?

Comment: Yeah please post it in question.

Comment: It still has the same error, by default the sessions are = 0 which displays all the data, i noticed the code doesn't account for it, could that be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
$sql = "SELECT value, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM sodsurvey LEFT OUTER JOIN age
ON sodsurvey.age_id = age.id 
WHERE value IS NOT NULL AND office_id = " . $office_id;

if(isset($_SESSION['filteryear']) && !empty($_SESSION['filteryear'])) {
    $sql . = "AND year = " . $_SESSION['filteryear']; 
}

if(isset($_SESSION['filtermonth']) && !empty($_SESSION['filtermonth'])) {
    $sql . = "AND month = " . $_SESSION['filtermonth']; 
}
$sql . = "GROUP BY age_id";


$result = $dbh->prepare($sql);//prepares query  
$result->execute();
```

Comment: I tried but it seems to collapse the charts and none of them render

Comment: I have updated the SQL... can you please try and let me know if you still facing any issue